# How do I create Github list of pull requests which are not approved by myself?

Tags: user-interface, github, pull-request

How do I create Github list of pull requested which are not approved by myself?

First of all, I would like to understand if this is possible to create custom lists of pull requests in Github.

Next, I would like to understand how can I find list of pull requests, which contain either request to be reviewed by myself or I have partially or completely reviewed them and requested changes on them.

If I used the following criteria in the pull requests page
`is:open is:pr review-requested:patlatus`
it won't show me the pull requests where I requested changes.

Comment: I don't know the exact answer, but have you consult [github API docs](https://developer.github.com)?

Comment: Do I have to use API for this? Is this possible to configure on UI without referring to API?